# Twitter API cursoring in Python

Tags: python, twitter

A python beginner here, trying to get [Twitter cursoring](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) working in my script so I might iterate all of the users that belong to a list on Twitter. Pretty simple logic here. Start with this API request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=all-fox-news&owner_screen_name=foxnews&cursor=-1
```

Then have a for loop alter the cursor =-1 to whatever the next_cursor_str is in parsed JSON. However, I'm having a hard time storing the next_cursor_str as a string. Has anyone had experience with this? Below is my code, works fine, just no cursor loop:

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv
from time import sleep

outfile_path='Out.csv'
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'w'))
headers = ['users']
writer.writerow(headers)

url = urllib2.Request('https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=all-fox-news&owner_screen_name=foxnews&cursor=-1')
parsed_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
print parsed_json
for tweet in parsed_json['users']:
    row = []
    row.append(str(tweet['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')))
    writer.writerow(row)
sleep(5)
```

Per the answer below parsed_json["next_cursor_str"] is exactly what I need. I thought a while loop would be good here, but yet it fails to end on 0:

```
n = parsed_json["next_cursor_str"]
int(n)
while n is not 0:
    url = urllib2.Request('https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=all-fox-news&owner_screen_name=foxnews&cursor=' + str(n))
    parsed_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    print parsed_json
    for tweet in parsed_json['users']:
        row = []
        row.append(str(tweet['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')))
        writer.writerow(row)
    n = parsed_json["next_cursor_str"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having trouble"? What specifically is not working about the code?

Comment: Not sure how to store next_cursor_str as a string

Comment: You don't have any variable called `next_cursor_str` in your code... Oh, you're referring to the field in the API. OK.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my answer solves it. If it doesn't, perhaps you could be clearer about what you mean by storing it as a string.

Comment: Your answer looks correct David.. I'll say just in case, but you are actually then using this value in your url request right? Maybe you should post your code with the loop you tried using if that isn't working.

Comment: It is indeed correct. I've added an attempt at cursoring above with the string, and it runs through the next_cursor_strings just fine, however, the while loop just seems to go on forever. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean to have the line `n = int(n)`- `int(n)` doesn't do anything on its own. You'd have to have that `int` in the last line too. But why bother? Why not just use `next_cursor` instead of `next_cursor_str`, which is already an int?

Comment: David, thank you so much. You've made my day. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next_cursor_str` is simply stored in your `parsed_json` variable:

```
print parsed_json["next_cursor_str"]
# 1395095221152647652
```

Comment: Thanks David. This is indeed it.